# Get a timespan in milliseconds using momentjs

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I try the following to get a timespan in milliseconds:

```
moment(0).minute(10).milliseconds()
```

The idea is to have a simple and readable way to convert timespans into milliseconds. But unfortunately this will always return `0`, the initial time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is what you actually want to do:

```
moment.duration(10, "minutes").asMilliseconds();
```

Comment: The first answers seems wrong, it returns `441`, `734` and so on. But the second one does what I'm looking for.

Comment: @AndreasKöberle Yeah, I realized that after submitting the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I got your question, but we can use JavaScript for timestamps

```
var start = new Date().getTime();
var elapsed = new Date().getTime() - start;
```